# Jetpack Compose - Blur view - Interop

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to interop blur view library into a composable to get a glass morphic ui .

I tried many ways with canvas but not worked well as this card should be inside a list. I found a good library Blur view here. But as of now it doesnt support compose.
It needs a viewgroup to be passed. Help me how to use this blur biew with Android view of jetpack compose.
It needs a viewgroup and window from activity please help to achieve this.

Library:
[2]: https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView